# Can a constant term be added to the new operators in the Bogoliubov transform?

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, bosons, cavity-qed, bosonization

The Bogoliubov transformation picks a set of boson operators $\{a_{k},a^{\dagger}_{k}\}$ and transforms them into a new set of boson operators generally written as:
\begin{equation}
b_{k}=\sum_{l} u_{kl}a_{l}+\sum_{p}u^{\prime}_{kp}a^{\dagger}_{p}
\end{equation}
I was now thinking: is this the most general transformation possible or would it be possible to use the following transformation:
\begin{equation}
b^{\prime}_{k}=\sum_{l} u_{kl}a_{l}+\sum_{p}u^{\prime}_{kp}a^{\dagger}_{p}+c
\end{equation}
where c is a constant.
I am asking this beacuse the commutator of a constant with something else is always zero so if $b_{k}$ and its complex conjugate $b^{\dagger}_{k}$ have bosonic commutation properties the same should be true also for $b^{\prime}_{k}$ and $b^{\prime\dagger}_{k}$. However, I can not find any place where this is reported so maybe there is some problem and I can't see it right now.

Edit. A very trivial example, consider the following Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
H= \sum_{l}\omega_{l}a^{\dagger}_{l}a_{l}+i\sum_{l}V_{l}\left(a_{l}-a^{\dagger}_{l}\right)+ \sum_{l}A_{l}(a^{2}_{l}+a^{\dagger\;2}_{l})
\end{equation}
If I want to bosonize this Hamiltonian I have to add a constant term to the boson operator right?

Comment: In the example: how is $a_{l\alpha}$ related to $a_l$?

Comment: It should be possible to "diagonalize" the Hamiltonian in the example without using the Bogoliubov transformation. Just complete the square.

Comment: Yes I agree on that, but if I wanted to see this as a Bogoliubov transformation this would mean that I added a constant in the guess of the bosonic field.... Another example might be this one

Answer (score 0):

The real question is: why would you do this tranformation or why would you define such an operator?

The Bogoliubov transformation is usually used to diagonalize Hamiltonians (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation)). Off-setting the operator by a constant does not change its time dependence. $b'_k$ is also stationary if $b_k$ is stationary. So all the additional constant does is offset the operator expectation values. I can not imagine a physical reason to perform this operation.

Comment: Well I was thinking that in order to find the new bosonic operators I have to ask for [b_{k},H]=\Omega b_{k} so if for example the Hamiltonian had some linear terms in it the photonic field like a_{l}+a^{\dagger}_{l} I would need constants in the definition of the new bosonic field right?

Comment: @Yepman It would be helpful if you could write out the example explicitly. I can’t imagine how the constant term would help in any example, but maybe I missed something.